# How to check the size of the sub-folder for a folder inside a Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: asp.net, amazon-s3

What i want to do is, i want to check the Size for a sub-folder inside a specific folder for a  bucket in Amazon S3 bucket using vb.

Is that possible to do, if so any link and help will be appriciated.

Comment: S3 is flat - there are no folders, just files with really long names and delimiters that make it appear to have folders. Are you wanting to find out the size of all objects stored with a common prefix? e.g. /ram/files/* ?

Comment: ok i am not very much familiar with amazon S3 and this is the case then it will help me in the problem. as if Ram is name of the bucket and files reside inside it, is this possible to fetch and restrict the max size for the files...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article [Beginning with Amazon S3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/186132/Beginning-with-Amazon-S3) is a good starting point for you. The code bits referencing the listObject method are doing 99% of what you want (getting all files with a particular prefix). You just need to add the bits to interrogate the file size of each and add them up.

If you're able to get the bucket, then you already have all the wire up you need for this snippet to work:

```
using (s3Client)
{

    long totalFileSize = 0;

    try
    {        
        ListObjectsRequest Lor = new ListObjectsRequest()
        {
            BucketName = "<Your Bucket Name>",
            Prefix = "<Your Folder Path>",
            ///assuming your delimiter is a /
            Delimiter = "/" 
        };  

        ListObjectsResponse response1 = s3Client.ListObjects(Lor);

        foreach (S3Object s3Object in response1.S3Objects)
        { 
            totalFileSize += s3Object.Size();
        }
    }

    catch (AmazonS3Exception ex)
    {
        ///do some error handling....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link but i already studied it. there were lot of things we have to implement, other stuff is done but i am struck in this one. we can fetch the bucket but i am not able to figure it out how to get the objects from inside the bucket and thier space consumption. it will be a great help if you can provide a example (if possible). thanks

Comment: thank you very much for the code and also for the investment of your valuable time, i will test it and let you know the results, thanks again.

Comment: Hello Mike s3Object.Size() is what i got in the s3Object and i am using the AWS Toolkit with revision number : {4F4C7530-C16D-4C75-9492-93207F03E902} : thanks and regards.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I updated the answer to reflect the property that worked for you.

Answer (score 5):

A little late to the party, but this works like a charm:

```
        AmazonS3 client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

        ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();
        request.WithBucketName(bucketName);
        request.WithPrefix(folderPath);
        long total = 0;
        do
        {
            ListObjectsResponse response = client.ListObjects(request);

            if (response != null && response.S3Objects != null)             
                total += response.S3Objects.Sum(s => s.Size);

            if (response.IsTruncated)
            {
                request.Marker = response.NextMarker;
            }
            else
            {
                request = null;
            }
        } while (request != null);
```

Your Access Key and Secret Access Key should by convention be saved to your application configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to enumerate through all the files on S3 you are looking at (e.g. with prefix /some/folder/ ) and add up all the sizes that come back. S3 does not know this information.

In VB you must be using some API, when you ask S3 to list the contents of a bucket with a prefix, the results come back about 1000 at a time, with size information for each file. So to add up the GB used for 25,000 files should only require 25 or so calls.

Comment: thanks for the reply as i said earlier i am newbie for Amazon S3 so it will be great if you can provide me a live link where i can see the approx way to do that (Hardly matters for me if it will be in C# or VB - i can work with both). Thanks again _Tom_ and sorry.

Comment: Any Example of multiple calls to bucket