# AWS sdk for ios android java get folder size

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, swift4

How to get s3 bucket/folder size for android and ios
i can get folder size using .net c# code from the following link but i couldn't find a code or api to get the same result in ios and android

[How to check the size of the sub-folder for a folder inside a Amazon S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888862/how-to-check-the-size-of-the-sub-folder-for-a-folder-inside-a-amazon-s3-bucket)

Thank you.

Comment: You need to use the `S3GetObjectMetadataRequest` and return the contentLength property on the response object. What have you tried? Where's your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my method used to get folder size from a s3 bucket android and java code :

```
public String GetFodlerSize() {

        String str = "";
        int Finalsize = 0;

        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accesskey,
                secretkey);
        AmazonS3 conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

        ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
                .withBucketName(BucketName).withPrefix(FolderName);
        ObjectListing objectListing;

        do {
            objectListing = conn.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
            for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing
                    .getObjectSummaries()) {

                str = (objectSummary.getSize() + "");
                int size = Integer.parseInt(str);

                Finalsize = Finalsize + size;

            }
            listObjectsRequest.setMarker(objectListing.getNextMarker());
        } while (objectListing.isTruncated());


        return FolderSize;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using This method i get folder size from a `aws s3` bucket ! Thanks@Gopi.cs

```
public void GetFodlerSize(Context context) {

            //s3 get details where you saved s3 credential 
            AmazonS3Client s3 = util.getS3Client(context);

            int Finalsize = 0;

            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

                String str = "";
                int Finalsize = 0;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,
                            "Loading",
                            "wait");
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... inputs) {
                    // Queries files in the bucket from S3.

                    ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest =
                            new ListObjectsRequest()
                                    .withBucketName(Constants.BUCKET_NAME)
                                    .withPrefix(NAME_OF_FOLDER_YOU_WANT_TO_GET_SIZE);

                    ObjectListing objects = s3.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);

                    for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary  : objects.getObjectSummaries() ) {
                        str = (objectSummary.getSize() + "");
                        int size = Integer.parseInt(str);

                        Finalsize = Finalsize + size;

                        objects = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(objects);
                    }

                    String sizeString = null;

                    if (Finalsize > 1024) {
                        Finalsize = Finalsize / 1024;
                        sizeString = " KB";
                    }
                    if (Finalsize > 1024) {
                        Finalsize = Finalsize / 1024;
                        sizeString = " MB";
                    }
                    if (Finalsize > 1024) {
                        Finalsize = Finalsize / 1024;
                        sizeString = " GB";
                    }

                    return ""+Finalsize+sizeString;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            }.execute();
        }
```

**Note :** I use AsyncTask because if you run without AsyncTask then you will get error like `don't run on Main Thread

Answer (score 1):

**For iOS Swift to get folder size of AWSS3 bucket folder**

```
func getFileSize(){
        let s3 = AWSS3.default()
        let getReq : AWSS3ListObjectsRequest = AWSS3ListObjectsRequest()
        getReq.bucket = self.bucketName
        getReq.prefix = "your folderPath" //Folder path to get size            
        let downloadGroup = DispatchGroup()
        downloadGroup.enter()

        s3.listObjects(getReq) { (listObjects, error) in

            var total : Int = 0

            if listObjects?.contents != nil {
                for object in (listObjects?.contents)! {
                    do {
                        let s3Object : AWSS3Object = object
                        total += (s3Object.size?.intValue)!
                    }
                }

                print(total)

                let byteCount = total // replace with data.count
                let bcf = ByteCountFormatter()
                bcf.allowedUnits = [.useMB] // optional: restricts the units to MB only
                bcf.countStyle = .file
                let string = bcf.string(fromByteCount: Int64(byteCount))
                print("File size in MB : \(string)")
            }
            else {
                print("contents is blank")
            }
        }
    }
```